Why is it giving me "_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!canvas" error?
This is the error I got when I tried to run my code:
PS D:\python projects> & "C:/Program Files/Python310/python.exe" "d:/python projects/assignments/animation/2danimation.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\python projects\assignments\animation\2danimation.py", line 20, in <module>
    coordinates = canvas.coords(small_bounce)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2795, in coords
    self.tk.call((self._w, 'coords') + args))]
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!canvas"
PS D:\python projects> 

This is my code, and the error seems to be on line twenty but I cant find one.
import tkinter
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler
import time
import winsound
WIDTH = 580
HEIGHT = 500
xvel =.25
yvel = .25
winsound.playsound("file name".winsound)
window = tkinter.Tk()
canvas = tkinter.Canvas(window, width = WIDTH, height = HEIGHT)
canvas.pack()
bg_image = tkinter.PhotoImage(file = "assignments/animation/ograng.png")
sb_image = tkinter.PhotoImage(file = 'assignments/animation/pixelbattleship.png')
small_bounce = canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=sb_image, anchor='nw')
background = canvas.create_image(250, 250, image = bg_image, anchor = "center")
sb_width = sb_image.width()
sb_height = sb_image.height()

while True:
    coordinates = canvas.coords(small_bounce)
    if (coordinates[0] >= (WIDTH - sb_width) or coordinates[0] < 0):
        xvel = -xvel
        xvel *= 1.01
    if (coordinates[1] >= (HEIGHT - sb_height) or coordinates[1] < 0):
        yvel = -yvel
        yvel *= 1.2
    canvas.move(small_bounce, xvel, yvel)
    window.update()
    #time.sleep(1)
    
window.mainloop()

I tried looking through the rest of the code, but it still isn't working and I couldn't fidn anything. My code is supposed to have a window open up and have a background, and then have a smaller picture bounce around the background and play a sound(I still need to finish the sound)

You have an infinite loop with while True:. How will you ever get to window.mainloop()?

This error usually means you've tried to use a widget after destroying it, but I don't see anything like that in the code you posted. Is this the whole code?

instead of while True you could use tkinter.after(milliseconds, function) to execute the same function again and again.

when you use canvas = tkinter.Canvas() then it doesn't create canvas but it only inform tkinter what it has to create when you run mainloop()or when you runupdate()first time. So maybe you should runwindow.update()at the beginning ofwhile-loop - before you use coordinates = canvas.coords(small_bounce). Or you could add extra update()beforewhile`-loop.

I get your error only when I close window - all because while-loop is running all time but window and canvas doesn't exist any more. You should use function which detect closing window and finish while-loop (ie, using variable to control loop while running: ). OR you should use tkinter.after

Your code works correctly for me. I get error only when I close window because it destroys window and canvas but it doesn't stop while-loop which what to access canvas.
It needs to catch close event and stop loop - using variable in while running:
running = True

def on_closing():
    global running
    running = False
    window.destroy()

window.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing)

while running:
     # ... rest of loop ...


Other method is to use tkinter.after(miliseconds, function) to execute code without while-loop - and tkinter will stop function when you close window.
def loop():
    global xvel
    global yvel
    
    coordinates = canvas.coords(small_bounce)
    if (coordinates[0] >= (WIDTH - sb_width) or coordinates[0] < 0):
        xvel = -xvel
        xvel *= 1.01
    if (coordinates[1] >= (HEIGHT - sb_height) or coordinates[1] < 0):
        yvel = -yvel
        yvel *= 1.2
    canvas.move(small_bounce, xvel, yvel)

    window.after(10, loop)  # run again after 10ms = 100 FPS (Frames Per Second) (1s = 1000ms) (1000ms/10ms = 100FPS)

window.after(10, loop) # run first time after 10ms 
window.mainloop()

It will run code every 10ms so it doesn't need time.sleep.
And it doesn't need tkinter.update()
